# sql case statement then insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, insert-update

i have stored procedure. the code looks like:

```
use nisa1415;
go
alter procedure dep.AddLessons
(   
    @LessonsTable nvarchar(50), 
    @LesDepId int,
    @TeId int,
    @GradeId varchar(10),
    @Activated int,
    @GroupId int,
    @TaskTable nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin select @LessonsTable=
case @LessonsTable when 'dep.les_Biology' then
  insert into dep.les_Biology(LesDepId,TeId,GradeId,Activated,GroupId,TaskTable) 
values(@LesDepId,@TeId,@GradeId,@Activated,@GroupId,@TaskTable) end 
return
end
```

it gives me an error:Incorrect syntax near 'insert'
what's the problem that i coudn't find?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns one of several possible values. It is **NOT** a flow control statement like `switch` in C# or in other languages. You'll have to use `IF ... THEN :..` to control the flow of your script execution

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER procedure AddLessons
(   
    @LessonsTable nvarchar(50), 
    @LesDepId int,
    @TeId int,
    @GradeId varchar(10),
    @Activated int,
    @GroupId int,
    @TaskTable nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin 
if @LessonsTable = 'dep.les_Biology'
begin
  insert into dep.les_Biology(LesDepId,TeId,GradeId,Activated,GroupId,TaskTable) 
values(@LesDepId,@TeId,@GradeId,@Activated,@GroupId,@TaskTable) end 
return
end
```